# Problem with Python POST request to an API

Tags: python, post, request

I'm making a post request to some endpoint but always receiving 404 while doing it from python but when I do it with CURL everything works. Here's my python code:

```
import requests 

def send_request(endpoint):

        api_keys = {'Api-Key': API_KEY,
                    'Api-Username': API_USERNAME}

        headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        request = requests.post(url = endpoint, data = api_keys, headers = headers)
        print("STATUS CODE: %s" % request.status_code)
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What does your CURL command look like? And please verify that `endpoint` matches the URL specified in the CURL command.

Comment: curl -X POST "https://community.myCompanyName.com/admin/plugins/explorer/queries/73/run" \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;" \
-H "Api-Key: <my_user_api_key>" \
-H "Api-Username: my_username"

Answer (score 0):

Run

`nc -lp 8080` (Linux) or `nc -l 8080` (macOS)

and then make the request using curl to http://localhost:8080 and note the headers. Run the above command again and this time make the request using Python. Note the headers again and compare them with the ones you got when making the request with curl. Are they the same?

Perhaps User-Agent is missing. Make sure to add the missing headers in Python.

Comment: They're the same. I added user agent but that didn't help

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If not, can you post screenshots from both requests?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get 200 with following code:

```
def send_request(endpoint):

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Api-Key': API_KEY, 'Api-Username': API_USERNAME}
    request = requests.post(url = endpoint, headers = headers)
    print("Request Status Code: {}".format(request.status_code))

    response = json.loads(request.text)

    return response_text
```

All needed to be sent in headers